# What is DMAC for Message Authentication Code?

Tags: cryptography, crypto++

I use MAC(Message Authentication Code) with Crypto++ library to secure MANET.
The library provides a lot of MACs algorithms.
I found DMAC in the MAC list and i don't know what does it mean?
[Message Authentication Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQrrF.png)

Best ragards
Hajji

Answer (score 0):

A bit hidden in the class description is a link:

> [CBC MAC for Real-Time Data Sources (08.15.1997)](https://eprint.iacr.org/1997/010) by Erez Petrank and Charles Rackoff

Which then points to the paper of which the description reads:

> We first present a variant of CBC MAC, called *double MAC* (DMAC) which handles messages of variable unknown lengths. Computing DMAC on a message is virtually as simple and as efficient as computing the standard CBC MAC on the message. We provide a rigorous proof that its security is implied by the security of the underlying block cipher. Next, we argue that the basic CBC MAC is secure when applied to prefix free message space. A message space can be made prefix free by authenticating also the (usually hidden) last character which marks the end of the message.

Double MAC consists of performing CBC-MAC followed by another CBC-MAC over the result, which should thwart length extension attacks on CBC-MAC.
I haven't heard of it before; I guess everybody uses CMAC instead nowadays. CMAC is more efficient as it only requires one additional run of the block cipher, and requires this up front (during initialization of the cipher).

Comment: Best method of thanking someone on StackExchange is to **accept the answer** and (once you are over 15 rep) to upvote it. Thank you comments and such are very polite, but still discouraged; glad you like it anyway :) Oh, and you can "clap" nowadays (all at the right side of the answer).

Comment: DMAC=EMAC? [link](https://www.erightsoft.com/help/HMACAlgo.htm)

Comment: Yep, looks like it. There are also implementations from CSPAN that claim the same thing. As indicated, this is not used much, so I'd always try to verify that implementations match though.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Where can I find test vectors about it?

Comment: Please ask separately on crypto.SE, I don't have any available directly. And vote up instead of asking additional questions if you find an answer useful.